# Prove that there is no a such that $a^{-1}(1,2,3)a = (1,3)(5,7,8)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

Herstein 2.10.8 (b)

Prove that there is no a such that $a^{-1}(1,2,3)a = (1,3)(5,7,8)$

My initial thought was that order of RHS and LHS permuation should be same.

For RHS, the cycles are disjoint, so order = lcm(2,3) = 6

And for LHS, I got to know that it has order 3.  And thus there is no such 'a' possible.

What I don't understand is how did we come to conclusion that $a^{-1}(1,2,3)a$ has order 3 ? Clearly (1,2,3) has order 3, but after taking product with some other permutation, will the order remain same, even if the cycles are not disjoint ?

Comment: $a^{-1} p a a^{-1} p a a^{-1} p a = a^{-1}p^{3}a = \ldots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any group $(x^{-1}gx)^{n}=x^{-1}g^n x$ and so $g^n=e$ if and only if $x^{-1} g^n x=e$ if and only if $(x^{-1}gx)^{n}=e$.

Comment: And in the above question, will we be able to comment anything about the order of a ?

Comment: Well in the above question there is NO such $a$, so I don't see what we could say.

Answer (score 3):

$a^{-1}pa$ must yield an element in the same conjugacy class as $p$, and conjugate elements have the same order.